# How to parse first name,last name , middle name and suffix with regex

Tags: javascript, etl, pentaho

I need a Regex for finding first name ,middle name, last name and suffix.

I am using this regex for

> First Name :  (\W).* Last Name: .+(\W)

Sample Data:
              ( David Nunes Jr. )
              ( Bill Quesenberry III )
              ( CG-William T. Keon III )

Comment: Can you give an example of the sample text?

Comment: ( David Nunes Jr. )    

( Bill Quesenberry III )

( CG-William T. Keon III )

Comment: If you want to do it in pdi then there is step called **splits field** fort that. you can defined delimeter as space